# Wordpress Contact Form Recipient Issue

Tags: forms, wordpress, content-management-system, sendmail, contacts

im built a form here: http://22twenty.com/wordpress/contact/

and its got the traditional code from a standard form

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> contact-send.php" class="validateform">

                    <div id="errormessage"></div>
                    <div id="sendmessage">
                        <p>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</p>
                    </div>  

                        <div class="formfield">
                            <input name="name" type="text"placeholder="Name:" class="text" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="formfield">
                            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email:" class="text" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="formfield">
                            <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject:" class="text" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="formfield">
                            <textarea name="message" class="text textarea" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here:" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="formfield">
                            <input type="submit" id="send" value="Post message"  class="btn" />
                        </div>

                </form>

  <?php $name = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";

$recipient = "get_option('admin_email')";

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
```

I'm wondering 2 things is this the best way to add a form and can i use the get_opition('admin_email') in this sense?

Thanks

Denver

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called [contact form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/). You can easily customize the total form and fore more option and feature you can check the documentation from their website. Hope this will work.

Comment: well if you take look at the link i added you'll see its all part of my custom page so i dont think that would work